# ESL question with/by/or something else

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> I need to modify a picture **with** pink color.

Or

> I need to modify a picture **by** pink color.

Or

> I need to modify a picture **using** pink color.

Which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean.

> I need to modify a picture with pink color.

or more naturally,

> I need to modify a picture with pink.
>
> I need to modify a picture with the color pink.

This sentence could be interpreted as saying you need to modify a picture by adding the color pink, either to change an existing color to pink or to mix it with pink (e.g. a black-and-white version of the Komen Foundation logo). It could also be interpreted as saying you need to modify in some unspecified way a picture which already contains the color pink (e.g. a picture of a carnation).

> I need to modify a picture using pink color.

i.e.

> I need to modify a picture using pink.
>
> I need to modify a picture using the color pink.

This sentence explicitly says you will apply the color pink to the picture, but I don't think sounds as natural as using "with."

The last example,

> I need to modify a picture by pink color.

is not typically used in English.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *modify a picture with pink* or *modify a picture using pink* but not *modify a picture by pink*.